# BigQuery: Unrecognized timezone when importing CSV

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, timezone, timestamp, google-bigquery

How can you define the **timezone** of a timestamp when loading into **BigQuery** from a **CSV** file?

none of these seem to work:

- 2018-07-31 11:55:00 Europe/Rome
- 2018-07-31 11:55:00 CET

I get the following error:

> {Location: "query"; Message: "Unrecognized timezone: Europe/Rome;
>   Could not parse '2018-07-31 11:55:00 Europe/Rome' as datetime for
>   field ts (position 0) starting at location 0"; Reason: "invalidQuery"}

I am running an import from Google Cloud Storage, using this Go code:

```
gcsRef := bigquery.NewGCSReference(gcsFilename)
gcsRef.SourceFormat = bigquery.CSV
gcsRef.FieldDelimiter = "|"
gcsRef.Schema = bigquery.Schema{
    {Name: "ts", Type: bigquery.TimestampFieldType},
    {Name: "field2", Type: bigquery.StringFieldType},
    {Name: "field3", Type: bigquery.StringFieldType},
}
loader := bigqueryClient.Dataset("events").Table("mytable").LoaderFrom(gcsRef)
loader.WriteDisposition = bigquery.WriteAppend

job, err := loader.Run(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("loader.Run", err.Error())
}
status, err := job.Wait(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln("job.Wait", err.Error())
}
if status.Err() != nil {
    log.Fatalln("Job completed with error: %v", status.Err(), status.Errors)
}
```

Comment: in your question you say you do (at least it sounds this way) load from CSV, but the error indicates you actually do a query - can you clarify please! meantime you can run `SELECT TIMESTAMP '2018-07-31 11:55:00 Europe/Rome', TIMESTAMP '2018-07-31 11:55:00 CET'` to confirm that both timezones are correct/valid

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I am running an import from Google Cloud Storage, using Go. I updated my question, specifying the code I am using.

Answer (score 1):

to make it work - try to declare `ts` field as string and then you will be able to resolve it into timestamp in whatever query you will then use - using already mentioned (in comment) approach - like `SELECT TIMESTAMP(ts)`

Comment: I would like to declare the field as TIMESTAMP, so that I can automatically partition the table on that field.

Comment: isn't there any way to specify that such timestamp is relative to a timezone different from UTC?

Comment: Or maybe a better solution would be to split that field in 2 different ones: date and time? And use the date as the partition field?

Comment: this should work - but in this case your partitioning will be not timezone aware

Comment: otherwise is there a way (during data loading) to specify the timezone of  the timestamp?

Comment: i really doubt there is a such an option :o(

Comment: so, would the only way be to convert the timestamp into UTC?

Comment: you mean convert to timestamp in csv before loading? it looks like the only option for you if doing so after load is done is not acceptable for your case

Comment: HI @Mikhail, can you please clarify one point. In case of using a TIMESTAMP as the partitioning column, the daily partitioning would be done according to UTC time, is this correct? So, as our company operates in CET, doesn't it make more sense to split by a DATE field expressed in CET? What do you think? Am I missing something?

Comment: @DanieleB, but you might [extract it specifying your own Timezone](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#timestamp). TIMESTAMP(string_expression[, timezone])-> Converts a STRING expression to a TIMESTAMP data type.

Comment: @Temu I am referring to table partitioning. As far as I understand, tables are partitioned by day, with one separate partition per day. As it's not possible to assign a timezone to a TIMESTAMP field, I assume that by having a TIMESTAMP as the partitioning column, the tables will be split by days according to UTC time.

Comment: You are totally right. Daily partitioning from "partitioned tables", as you said, will be done [according to UTC time](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#comparing_partitioning_options). If you use DATE then you can [specify the exact timezone](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date). 

You could use, as you said, both columns, DATE and [TIME](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#time) in order to be able to specify Timezone which is not UTC.